# Target specific element in label class

Tags: html, css, shopify, liquid

On my Shopify store, I'm trying to target a span inside a label and some divs, to add some CSS, but I can't do it.

I want to make the SECOND span "eraser_text" font red. There is a total of 3 eraser text spans, one for each product variant, I just want to modify the 2nd one.

```
<label class="selectorv2" for="{{ section.id }}-{{ forloop.index0 }}">
   <div class="sn_ys">
      <span class="swatch_title">{{ variant.title }}</span>
      <span class="eraser_text">{{ variant.metafields.custom.variantqty }}</span>
      <div class="swtch_you_save">{{ variant.metafields.custom.variantoffer }}</div>
   </div>
   <div class="prie_grp">
      <span class="var_price">{{ variant.price | money }}</span>
      <span class="var_prce">
      <s class="var_com_price">{{ variant.compare_at_price | money }}</s> 
      </span>
   </div>
</label>
<label class="selectorv2" for="{{ section.id }}-{{ forloop.index0 }}">
   <div class="sn_ys">
      <span class="swatch_title">{{ variant.title }}</span>
      <span class="eraser_text">{{ variant.metafields.custom.variantqty }}</span>
      <div class="swtch_you_save">{{ variant.metafields.custom.variantoffer }}</div>
   </div>
   <div class="prie_grp">
      <span class="var_price">{{ variant.price | money }}</span>
      <span class="var_prce">
      <s class="var_com_price">{{ variant.compare_at_price | money }}</s> 
      </span>
   </div>
</label>
<label class="selectorv2" for="{{ section.id }}-{{ forloop.index0 }}">
   <div class="sn_ys">
      <span class="swatch_title">{{ variant.title }}</span>
      <span class="eraser_text">{{ variant.metafields.custom.variantqty }}</span>
      <div class="swtch_you_save">{{ variant.metafields.custom.variantoffer }}</div>
   </div>
   <div class="prie_grp">
      <span class="var_price">{{ variant.price | money }}</span>
      <span class="var_prce">
      <s class="var_com_price">{{ variant.compare_at_price | money }}</s> 
      </span>
   </div>
</label>
```

I tried things like (probably has 0 sense):

```
selectorv2 > sn_ys > span.eraser_text:nth-child(1) {
  color:red;
  }
  
  label[for="template--15693574144162__main-1"] > eraser_text {
  color: red;
}
  
  selectorv2 > label[for="template--15693574144162__main-1"] > sn_ys > eraser_text{
   color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to put dots when you are using classes to select elements.

```css
.selectorv2 > .sn_ys > span:nth-child(2) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<label class="selectorv2" for="{{ section.id }}-{{ forloop.index0 }}">
   <div class="sn_ys">
      <span class="swatch_title">{{ variant.title }}</span>
      <span class="eraser_text">{{ variant.metafields.custom.variantqty }}</span>
      <div class="swtch_you_save">{{ variant.metafields.custom.variantoffer }}</div>
   </div>
   <div class="prie_grp">
      <span class="var_price">{{ variant.price | money }}</span>
      <span class="var_prce">
      <s class="var_com_price">{{ variant.compare_at_price | money }}</s> 
      </span>
   </div>
</label>
```

Then, you do not need to use nth-child when you already have a unique element with `.eraser-text`.